# Use threshold values in an if-else block as a key for a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

My current if-else block looks like this -

```
def do_something(value):
    if value <= 0: 
        return 1
    elif value > 0 and value < 5:
        return 2
    else:
        return 3
```

Please note that the example is not a direct representation of my code. I have significantly reduced the number of if-else blocks for the sake of brevity. What I would like to do is create a dictionary that can hold the threshold values for each condition as a key. Here's an example of what i mean by this.

```
   dict_factory_pattern = {
                              0: 1,
                              1-4: 2,
                              5-inf: 3
                           }
   # With the dictionary structure above I want to refactor my do_something () to as shown below

    def do_something(value):
        
       return dict_factory_pattern[value]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You cannot achieve that with a dictionary.

Comment: You could achieve that but you'll need to write every possible value in your dict and the final else would be triggered by a KeyError exception that you'd catch

Comment: @Plopp: Cannot, because there are infinitely many values <= 0, and (not that it matters that much at this point) "another" infinitely many values >= 5.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb is right. My use case will definitely encounter float values between 1-4. Are you aware of techniques that could reduce the time complexity? If I'm not wrong, the worst-case scenario would be O(n). So the highest threshold that I need to evaluate for is 360(here inf = 360 so range for final else would be 5-360). If I were to create a list of numbers ranging from 0-360, could I perform binary sort on it and potentially reduce time complexity to O(logn)? Im sorry if these questions are basic, but I'm still learning the ropes.

Comment: @Plopp Would love to hear what you have to say on this too

Comment: The time complexity of method `do_something` is `O(1)`, so you'll have to explain better how exactly you've concluded `O(n)` here.

Comment: So suppose I have 6 conditions including the else and if the else condition evaluates to true, it's because all the other checks failed. So wouldn't the total time complexity of the number of checks performed be O(6) as n in this case is 6? This was my reasoning behind why I said O(n).

Comment: O(1) and O(6) are equivalent because both mean "constant time", as opposed to O(n) which means "linear in the length of the input".

Comment: @JanWilamowski That clears my confusion. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an [interval tree](https://pypi.org/project/intervaltree/). Note that its boundary values are such that the lower bound is included but the upper bound is not.

```py
# pip install intervaltree
from intervaltree import IntervalTree

tree = IntervalTree()
tree[float('-inf'):0] = 1
tree[0:5] = 2
tree[5:float('inf')] = 3

def find_value(n):
    interval = tree[n]
    if interval:
        result = sorted(interval)[0]
        return result.data

[find_value(n) for n in [-0.5, 0, 0.5, 10]] # gives [1, 2, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the amount of code, you could declare the threshold values in a dict and iterate over them. This is essentially the same as having multiple `if` statements, except you don't have to spell them out yourself. You do however loose the flexibility of multiple conditions since the same comparison (e.g. less than or equal) is applied to all threshold values. The compactness of the rule set may be worth it.

```py
thresholds = {
    0: 1,
    5: 2,
    float('inf'): 3,
}

def find_value(n):
    for threshold, result in thresholds.items():
        if n <= threshold:
            return result

[find_value(n) for n in [-0.5, 0, 0.5, 10]] # gives [1, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary cannot do such thing. The selection alone can be done by a conditional. Assume your input is value

```
value = int(input("input value"))
res = 1 if value <= 0 else 2 if 1 <= value <= 4 else 5
```

I notice it's a factory pattern you are concerning. So for example you have three Object you want to create (build) then do

```
class FrogWorld:
    pass

class Wizard:
    pass

class StreetFighter:
    pass


value = int(input("input value"))
res = FrogWorld if value <= 0 else Wizard if 1 <= value <= 4 else StreetFighter
```

res will be the made now. This is just a short answer. It can be more elaborate expression for this